# Import documentation field from test cases from robot to test in XRAY

Tags: robotframework, jira, jira-xray

Im currently working on a project were i'm importing the output.xml from my test suite to JIRA via XRAY. This create the test (in case they don't exists already) and the execution test (with the results).

My problem is that right now, the test are created without description or documentation. Is there a way were I can set the `[Documentation]` field from the test cases in robot to the JIRA issue (test) via XRAY? I don't find anything in the XRAY API doc.

Maybe my only option is parse all the `[Documentation]` field of the tests cases and then import in the test on JIRA without XRAY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not yet possible but it make sense in my perspective.
You can vote and follow [this suggestion](https://jira.getxray.app/browse/XRAY-7949) so the Xray can be aware about your interest on it.
You can implement your own script to go over the Tests and update the Description field (using Jira's REST API) but you would need to know their key in advance; if that's the case, then fine.

Comment: Thank you! I have voted the ticket to give it more visibility